# Why my txt file has been changed after I used pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

the orignal data is:

[image]

the output data is:

[image]

```
    import pandas as pd

    signal_data = pd.read_csv('B.txt').T
    print pd.read_csv('B.txt').T

    dates = pd.date_range('2015-10-1', periods=19)

    signal_data_df= pd.DataFrame(signal_data, index=dates, columns=['PCLN', 'SPY', 'QCOM', 'AAPL', 'USB', 'AMGN', 'GS', 'BIIB', 'AGN'])
    print signal_data_df
```

Comment: Are you trying to rename the column?

Comment: yes, rename the index and column, but the point is the "1" signal has disappeared.

Comment: As EdChum mentioned use `df.columns` to rename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you pass a df as the data source, it's reusing the index and columns from the df so when you pass an alternative index and column values you're effectively reindexing the original df hence the `NaN` values everywhere. You can just rename the columns and overwrite the index directly:

```
signal_data = pd.read_csv('B.txt').T
signal_data.columns=['PCLN', 'SPY', 'QCOM', 'AAPL', 'USB', 'AMGN', 'GS', 'BIIB', 'AGN']
signal_data.index = dates
```

or to get your code to work call `.values` to return the df as anonymous np array data:

```
signal_data_df= pd.DataFrame(signal_data.values, index=dates, columns=['PCLN', 'SPY', 'QCOM', 'AAPL', 'USB', 'AMGN', 'GS', 'BIIB', 'AGN'])
```

Comment: I was about mention 'df.columns' I saw your answer then when saw second option cant resist up vote :)